# how to put <hr/> between every node in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

hi again i just want to put a `<hr>` tag between every page node to separate the content

this is XML File

**XML:**

```
<site>
   <page>
  <content><p align="center"> thank you</p>
   <P align="center">
     <FONT size="2" face="Tahoma">
       <p>some data too</p>
     </FONT>
   </P>
  </content>
   </page>
   <page>
  <content><p>some data</p>
    </content>
    </page>
    </site>
```

and this is xsl File

**XSL:**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:copy-of select="site/page/content"/><hr/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem that the line is shown at the end of the out put and I need it between every page node
thank u

Comment: Please remember to show any output you expect in these situations. That way there is less chance of a misunderstanding about what your require. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template based approach here. Have a template that matches the **content** element where you just copy that node's data, and put the **hr** element after it

```
<xsl:template match="content">
   <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
   <hr />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of doing `<xsl:copy-of select="site/page/content"/>` do `<xsl:apply-templates select="site/page/content"/>` instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="site/page/content"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="content">
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      <hr/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<hr />` is not displayed un my case... so I added `border-bottom="1px solid #000"` in the table tag.